# Pipe data without EOF? Possible?

Tags: bash, netcat

I am trying to write a bash script that opens an FTP connection in nc that remains open in the background.  I have:

```
(echo "USER o:)"; echo "PASS foo")| nc -d 192.168.56.101 21 &
```

but the connection is closing immediately.  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks a ton

Comment: You should not be backgrounding a process like this. Please include in your post the reason for your backgrounding requirement and better solutions can be provided

Answer (score 1):

I got it: add a read to the chain!